# HTTP Status codes via Powershell

Tags: powershell, http, http-status-codes

Somehow the below codes works fine for the first few test URLs within C:\testurl.txt then it hung up forever when it is processing the 4th URL from the C:\testurl.txt , no idea why it hangs up?

It is already working fine for up to 3 URLs but stuck up on 4th onward

```
CLS
$urllist = Get-Content "C:\testurl.txt" # URLs to test one in each line
foreach ($url in $urllist) {
    Write-Host $url

    $req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)

    try {
        $res = $req.GetResponse()
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        $res = $_.Exception.Response
    }

    $res.StatusCode
    #Print OK or whatever

    [int]$res.StatusCode
    #Print 200 or whatever
}
```

It is working fine for up to 3 URLs but hangs the script on 4th URL without any output or error message. Here is the example of c:\testurl.txt

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com     
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.hotmail.com
http://www.gmail.com
http://www.yahoo.com
http://www.msn.com
```

Please note each URL will be in a new line, you will see that script will stop at (the 4th one) you may try with your own URLs, etc too

Comment: That 4th URL being ... *what?*

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers If you add multiple URLs to test in the file c:\testurl.txt for example: www.google.com www.hotmail.com www.gmail.com www.yahoo.com www.msn.com     then you you will see that script will stop at www.yahoo.com (the 4th one)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It will throw an error for all of them if you specify just the FQDNs without protocol scheme, though.

Comment: please, add the list with the failing URL to your Original Post.

Comment: lee_Dailey  here is the example of c:\testurl.txt  http://www.google.com http://www.hotmail.com http://www.gmail.com http://www.yahoo.com http://www.msn.com please note each URL will be in new line, you will see that script will stop at http://www.yahoo.com (the 4th one) you may try with your own URLs etc too (please note http//www. is there before every URL however it is not displayed here)

Comment: @M-ACharlotte - PLEASE add the list to your ORIGINAL POST. [*frown*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have added the examples of URLs in the original post, thanks!

Comment: @M-ACharlotte - good! now ... put them in code format so that folks can read them ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey c:\testurl.txt is just a plain text file outside the script it is not supposed to be a code itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then it hung up forever

No - it's hung until the underlying TCP connections of the previous requests time out.

The .NET CLR will internally pool all `WebRequest` dispatches so that only a finite number of external requests will be initiated concurrently, and as long as you have a number of un-closed `WebResponse` objects in memory, your requests will start queuing up.

You can avoid this by closing them (as you should):

```
foreach ($url in $urllist) {
    Write-Host $url

    $req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)

    try {
        $res = $req.GetResponse()
    } 
    catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        $res = $_.Exception.Response
    }
    finally {
        $res.StatusCode
        #Print OK or whatever

        [int]$res.StatusCode
        #Print 200 or whatever

        $res.Dispose()
        # close connection, dispose of response stream
    }
}
```

Comment: Its perfect! I missed out that Disposing of the stream and that's why it was hanging up after a few URLs, Thanks for the help!